# Do other apps use tor when the browser bundle is running?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, deanonymization

For example if I run curl from the command line does this go through tor? what about spottify, or other browsers?

If so, is this a risk, can I access the internet from other apps while i'm using the tor browser bundle?

Sorry about the basic question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from the Tor Project [download page](https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html.en):

> Tor does not protect all of your computer's Internet traffic when you
>   run it. Tor only protects your applications that are properly
>   configured to send their Internet traffic through Tor. To avoid
>   problems with Tor configuration, we strongly recommend you use the Tor
>   Browser. It is pre-configured to protect your privacy and anonymity on
>   the web as long as you're browsing with the Tor Browser itself. Almost
>   any other web browser configuration is likely to be unsafe to use with
>   Tor.